# Java Font Size vs HTML Font Size

Tags: java, graphics

I am writing text on an image . I am using DrawString(x,y,string) method and I set font size as below

```
Font font = new Font(fontName, fontWeight, fontSize);
```

[image]

As you can see left side text written on image with 12pt size. Right side you can see 12pt size in HTML . Is there any way to map this so that I get same size in output as user sees in HTML ?

Comment: It looks like the Java version doesn't use pt as unit, but pixels.

Comment: It does use pt cause drawstring method has size as point . Kensen's solution fixed it.

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202225/java-fontmetrics-ascent-incorrect . Java font size seems to take into accounts letters with diacritics but HTML not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [this link](http://www.3rd-evolution.de/tkrammer/docs/java_font_size.html). Maybe useful. Try it out.

Basically it says that

```
Java assumes 72 dpi screen resolution Windows uses 96 dpi or 120 dpi depending 
on your font size setting in the display properties.
```

The site suggests

```
instead of using getNormalizingTransform() you have to use getScreenResolution()
```

From the website again.

```
int screenRes = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();
int fontSize = (int)Math.round(12.0 * screenRes / 72.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

I *believe* this is because java assumes 72 dpi display, where most everything else uses 96dpi now?

see: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html